# How to access the parent intent data members into started activity in android(JAVA)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

How to access data of the Starting activity into Started activity.
like i have given the following snippet for better understanding.

**BaseActivity.java**

```
class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
...
btnCust = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCust);      
    btnCust.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String flag ="CU";
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ChildActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("flag", flag);
            startActivity(i);
         }
    });

    public int add(int a,int b){
      return a+b;
    }
...
}
```

Now how to access **BaseActivity Add() Method** into **ChildActivity**.

**ChildActivity.java**

```
class ChildActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
...
btnCust = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCust);      
    btnCust.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String flag ="CU";
            BaseActivity a = getBaseActivity();///here i want read the object of base activity       
            int add = a.add(20,50);
        }
    });
...
}
```

Can anyone know that how to solve this problem which is i`m trying too much time.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

I have tried with Serializable and Parcelable, but still not working.

Comment: You can't. You can start ChildActivity and receive a result from it but accessing previous activity's variables is a no go.

Comment: Well that is not possible the way you tried. You cannot get a pointer to an activity and hence you cannot call methods of it. If you used startActivityForResult() (deprecated but there is a new one) you could finish the childactivity with the data in the resulting intent. The main activity then catches from that the data and calls that function.

Comment: Yes I want like that. Is there any option to do that?

Comment: If the method doesn't need any member variables from the `Activity`, you can declare the method as `public static` and it can be called from anywhere.

Otherwise, if you need to pass data between the activities, you can add the data as "extras" in the `Intent`.

Comment: Indeed.. i only now see that it just adds.... Well what a fuss.. The child activity could do it.. it will be just an example we hope.

Comment: Because, it reduces the code for write for each activity. That`s why  i`m trying that.

Comment: Yes someone has said me that. it is possible!!!.

Comment: Consider using one activity rather than two, with fragments (or composables) to represent the screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel#:%7E:text=ViewModel%20is%20a%20class%20that,calling%20the%20business%20logic%20classes) and move your logic into it and use them into shareable in any activity, fragment or composable screens.

Comment: can you share this answer with some code snippet?